# Objective-C – Finding out textLabel's position inside an UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I would like to find out the default x position of the `textLabel` property of an `UITableViewCell`. What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Cheers,

Peter

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? I may be able to provide better information if you describe your situation a little.

Comment: I'm creating my own subclass of UITableViewCell and I just want to mimic as much as possible of the original UITableViewCell class that Apple has provided. So that's why I wanted to know the x-position of textLabel so I can place my labels at the same x-position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.textLabel.frame.origin.x
```

Gives you the position of the textLabel relative to its containing view.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the x position of a UILabel by getting its `frame.origin.x` property. So for a cell's label, you would use `cell.textLabel.frame.origin.x`.

Note that there's not much you can do with the default `textLabel` and `detailLabel` in a `UITableViewCell`. Your best bet is often to [create custom cell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) and use that.